# Improve and complete the proof of : If $X$ is infinite and $I \subseteq N$, then $ X\cup I \approx X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

**Prove that if $X$ is infinite and $I \subseteq N$, then $ X\cup I \approx X$**

I have this proof in my lecture notes:

Let's suppose for simplicity that $X \cap I =\phi$ and let $\varphi : N \rightarrow X $ be an injective mapping with $Z=Im(\varphi)$, If $I=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\}$
Let'consider the table:

[image]

and let's define $\psi: Z \rightarrow Z\cup I$ following the arrows.

Now the mapping:

[[image: <span class=]$\vartheta:X \rightarrow X\cup I $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ND6.png)

is a bijection. It is easy to modify the argument to understand the case in which $X \cap I \neq \phi$.

I don't get how they construct $\psi$ and manage to show that it is a bijection. I know from a similar proof (Dedekind's criterion) that they a trying to make $\psi$ a bijection so that the composition with $\varphi$ would give a bijection and then expand the resulting bijection with $ X \setminus Z $ to get $\vartheta$. the slanted arrows make no sense to me, since the elements of $I$ are disjoint with $X$ and $Z$, so they couldn't be part of the domain of $\psi$, could they? Besides they don't say anything about I, so it could be finite or infinite.

Could someone shed some light and do the modified argument for the case $X \cap I \neq \phi$ ?

Comment: $N$ is the set of natural numbers by the way

Comment: What does the $\approx$ relation mean in this context?

Comment: @abiessu it means equinumerosity.  Two sets or classes A and B are equinumerous if there exists a one-to-one correspondence (a bijection) between them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver Any two infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ are equinumerous; this is not hard to prove. In your case, $X$ and $X\cup I$ are clearly both infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think that the first diagram actually quite matches what was intended. The point is that $Z\cup I$ is countably infinite, so it can be enumerated as follows. If $I=\{\lambda_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ is infinite, then we define

$$f:\Bbb N\to Z\cup I:k\mapsto\begin{cases}
\varphi\left(\frac{k+1}2\right),&\text{if }k\text{ is odd}\\
\lambda_{k/2},&\text{if }k\text{ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

If $I=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$, we define

$$f:\Bbb N\to Z\cup I:k\mapsto\begin{cases}
\varphi\left(\frac{k+1}2\right),&\text{if }k\le 2n\text{ and }k\text{ is odd}\\
\lambda_{k/2},&\text{if }k\le 2n\text{ and }k\text{ is even}\\
\varphi(k-n),&\text{if }k>2n\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then we define $\psi:Z\to Z\cup I:\varphi(n)\mapsto f(n)$, i.e., $\psi=f\circ\varphi^{-1}$.

Now suppose that $X\cap I\ne\varnothing$. Let $J=I\setminus X$. Then $X\cup I=X\cup J$, and $X\cap J=\varnothing$, so $|X\cup I|=|X\cup J|=|X|$.

Comment: X is not necessarily countable infinite. It is, in general an  uncountable set. In the proof of Dedekind's criterion, they start using the following proposition: If a set X is infinite, then there exists an injection from the natural numbers to X, and then go on with a similar trick as described.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: At no point did I assume that $X$ is countably infinite. Read it again: I used the fact that $Z$ is countably infinite.

Comment: You're right, my bad. $\psi$ should be a bijection, right?, so then why is f a bijection?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: $f$ is a bijection in order to make $\psi$ a bijection.

Comment: yeah, just wondering how do I see $f$ it is injective and surjective

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: That should be pretty easy to see if $I$ is infinite: it just lists $Z\cup I$ in the order of the arrows in the diagram. If $I$ is finite, it starts out that way, and when it runs out of members of $I$, it just continues the listing of $Z$. If $n=3$, for instance, $f$ lists $\varphi(1),\lambda_1,\varphi(2),\lambda_2,\varphi(3),\lambda_3,\varphi(4),\varphi(5),\ldots\;$.

Comment: ok, but this proves $\psi$ is a bijection from $Z$ to $Z\cup I$ but we need a bijection from $X$ to $X\cup I$

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: And that is exactly what $\theta$ is! Since you said nothing about $\theta$, I assumed that you understood how it was constructed from $\psi$, the bijection from $Z$ to $Z\cup I$.

Comment: ok, Intuitively I guess it is because $\theta$ the union of two disjoint bijections, not sure if a need to summon some theorem for rigurosity.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: The fact that $\theta$ is the union of bijections whose domains are disjoint and whose ranges are also disjoint immediately shows that $\theta$ itself is a bijection; nothing more is needed.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott I think instead of $J=X\setminus I$ it should be $J=I\setminus X$. The point is to have a partition of $X \cup I$, right? to make the problem fall in the previous case.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Oops! Yes, that was definitely a typo. Thanks!